# Add onclick event to command field in asp.net DetailsView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this `command field` in `DetailsView`.

```
<asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" CancelText="Reset" />
```

When user click this link, it inserts the user filled data in `DetailsView` into database. But I want to set text to two text boxes in this `DetailsView` before inserting. I can do it in code behind. I have tried this by adding `OnItemInserting` event to `DetailsView`. But it's not working. Data set in code behind not inserted to database.

code behind

```
protected void ABC_DV_ItemInserting(Object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
        {

  TextBox p = (TextBox)LKArea_DV.FindControl("txt_p");

  TextBox x= (TextBox)ABC_DV.FindControl("txt_x");
  TextBox y= (TextBox)ABC_DV.FindControl("txt_y");

  string[] q = p.Text.Trim().Split(',');

  x.Text = q[0];
  y.Text = q[1];

       }
```

How could I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245755/add-onclick-event-to-command-field-in-asp-net

Comment: @karthi i have tried it. but not working. text box data i have set in code behind, not in database table after inserting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132795/how-to-retrieve-a-textbox-from-detailsview-asp-net

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045617/asp-net-setting-the-value-of-a-detailsview-textbox

Answer (score 0):

Use ItemCommand Event

1. Get Controls like Textbox from your DetailView control.
2. Check if they are NULL
3. If not null then grab the values
4. Perform Insert , update any operation you like
5. Commit the changes
6. Rebind your control

It should work. hope that helps